# Calling a library function with rust-abi

Tags: rust, ld, ffi

I have a couple of crates X and Y. The first ones manages low-level stuff and defines an entry point. Then it should transfer control to the Y, which do high-level logic. I would like to explicitly declare Y's function in X and call it (so the linker connects these while building Y-crate).

I know Rust has non-stable ABI, but I use both of these crates in one workspace with the same compiler.

I tried with the following example, but the linker cannot find `real_main` (undefined reference ...):

```rust
// X's main.rs
#[link(name = "y_lib_name", link = "static")]
extern "Rust" {
    fn real_main();
}

fn main() {
    // is it possible to avoid unsafe here, btw?
    unsafe { real_main() }
}


// Y's lib.rs
pub fn real_main() { .. }
```

Though the symbol exists:

```sh
$ nm target/debug/deps/liby_lib_name-8ade2b95fe4044c6.rlib | rg real_main
nm: lib.rmeta: file format not recognized
0000000000000000 T _ZN8y_lib_name9real_main17h8664760a5d2676beE
```

I guess my issue can be resolved via macro in X like the following:

```rust
// in X
#[macro_export]
macro_rules define_ep! {
  ($fn:expr) => {{ fn main() { $fn(); } }}
}


// in Y
fn f() {}

X::define_ep!(f);
```

but I would prefer the linker-backed way because:

- if you forgot linker just give you an error;
- (not sure) linker gives an error if symbols appears more than once.

Comment: I think you need some #[no_mangle] like here: https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/uses-for-no-mangle-with-rust-abi/7293/5

Comment: Hmm, I see. But I think it has some limitations (e.g. generics usage, particularly useful for lifetimes), right?

Comment: Sadly I'm not an expert on this topic, I just remembered reading this thread a while ago.

Comment: generics are monomorphized so it shouldn't be issue?